# Is there any built-un function in Java to reverse the array from one specified index to another index?

Tags: java, arrays

For example:
My array is `[1,2,3,4]` and I want to reverse it from index 1 to 2. So my answer should be `[1,3,2,4]`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: *"what can i do that i will find my required result"* --- Write some code. Do a **web search** if you don't know how to reverse the values in an array.

Comment: The closest thing that is built-in are `Collections::reverse` and `Arrays::copyOfRange` with some extra logic

Comment: Pseudo-code: `for (i = firstIndex, j = lastIndex; i < j; i++, j--) { /* swap values of arr[i] and arr[j] */ }`

Comment: This solution is good.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple:

```
public static void reverseRangeClose(int[] arr, int fromIndexInclusive, int toIndexInclusive) {
    for (int i = fromIndexInclusive, j = toIndexInclusive; i < j; i++, j--) {
        int tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));   // [1, 2, 3, 4]
reverseRangeClose(arr, 0, 2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));   // [3, 2, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify your array as an Object array and not a primitive array you can do it like this.

```
Integer[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(a).subList(3,7));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

It works because the `Arrays.asList` uses your array to back up the list. The sublist specifies which part of the list (and thus the array) to reverse.

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4, 8, 9, 10]
```

For a primitive array, you can do it like this. This is what @Andreas was talking about.  The only difference is that the end is `exclusive` to conform to standard practices in most languages when specifying ranges.  And I also throw an exception when the beginning index is greater than the ending index.

```
public static void reverse(int[] a, int begin, int end) {
    if (begin > end) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format("begin(%d) > end(%d)", begin, end));
    }
    for (int i = begin, j = end-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        int t1 = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = t1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If my array is a primitive array then what approach can i use?